ResourceフォルダにエクスポートしたFBXファイルをscriptからRigのAnimation Typeを「Humanoid」に変更したい
Unityで開発しております。
ResourceフォルダにエクスポートしたFBXファイルをscriptからRigのAnimation Typeを「Humanoid」に変更したいと考えております。
これは出力されるFBXファイルが「Generic」形式でしか出力されないためであります。
最終的には出力されたFBXファイルをアプリ実行中に読み込み、AnimatorControllerを作成して、画面上に表示しているAnimatorの
Controllerに設定することで、人型モデルの動作が切り替わることを目標としております。
よろしくお願い致します。
開発環境
OS:Windows
Unityバージョン:2020.3.48f1


最終的には出力されたFBXファイルをアプリ実行中に読み込み

そもそも、これがUnity標準ではできません。
Resources.LoadなどでのFBXファイルのアセットの読み込みは、ビルド時に最適なデータに変換されたものを読み込んでいるわけでして、FBXファイルを読んでいるわけではありません。
つまり、実行時にはFBXファイルを読む機能はありません。
そのような処理をしたことがありませんので詳しくはありませんが、「unity fbx runtime」で検索すると、「TriLib2」というパッケージを使うのが、一つの手段のようです。
もしくは、「FBX SDK for Unity」というパッケージもあるようですが、マニュアルを見る限り、使えるのがPCのみであったり、そもそも「SDK for Unity」だからSDKを把握していないと使えないなど、色々と大変そうです。
他にも手段があるようなので、先程言った「unity fbx runtime」などで検索してみてください。

というわけで、回答としては無意味かもしれませんが、エディタ上であれば ModelImporter.animationTypeにModelImporterAnimationType.Humanを設定すれば、Humanoid設定になると思います。
